# Kubernetes multiple NetworkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Suppose I have 2 network policies for two different podSelectors

### Policy 1:

doesn't allow any egress traffic for pod labeled by app=core

### Policy 2:

allow egress traffic to CIDR 10.0.0.0/8 for pods labeled by type=internal

### Pod:

1 pod labeled by both labels app=core, type=internal

Is there any way to know what is the combination of those rules?

The network plugin used is Canal

Comment: will that help you? https://serverfault.com/a/952221/477518